# As of now I'm in twitter login page i need to navigate back to home page and after that i need to click on facebook icon - script for selenium

Tags: selenium

After clicking on twiiter icon i navigate to twitter login page now i need to back to home page and i need to click on facebook icon.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath()).click(); used
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to navigate back then use

```
  driver.navigate().back();
```

which is equivalent to browser back. Then try click on other icon

Thank You,
Murali